# Can we use AWS Lambdas to check if any mandatory policy is not missing for all newly created roles

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

how can we make sure that a particular policy ( say S3 bucket access restriction policy ) is attached to all newly created Roles.

Can we write a Lambda that gets triggered only when a new Role is created and check and if missing attached required policies?

AttachRolePolicy API can be used to attach policy to a role. Are there any examples available in AWS Lambda to get this done?

Does Terraform provides any such modules readily available that can be referred in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can configure a lambda function that's triggered by EventBridge via CloudTrail when a specific AWS API is called. Take a look at the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-eventbridge-cloudtrail-rule.html). Since this is pretty simple, I don't think there is a specific module created for this. You can write your own directly based on the resources in the AWS provider.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc. I am able to configure a Lambda function and able to get an event using EventBridge for "CreateRole" event from AWS.IAM.

Answer (score 0):

Python SDK for AWS **Boto3**, is having multiple APIs that can be used like adding a role, policy etc. It is very simple and documentation is awesome.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html

an example to attach a policy to an existing role:

```
client= boto3.resource('iam')
response = client.attach_role_policy(
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess',
    RoleName='ReadOnlyRole',
)
```

Similarly other clients can be grabbed for other AWS services.